# Firefox SDK JPM error when trying to attach scripts on tab ready event

Tags: firefox-addon-sdk

This started on 02-11-2016 - firefox developer edition (but apparently also the main one)

Code:

```
var self = require("sdk/self");
var tabs = require("sdk/tabs");
tabs.on('ready', function(tab){
  tab.attach({
    contentScriptFile: [self.data.url('js/my-file.js')]
  })
});

console.error:
JPM [error]   Message: Error: Creating URI from string failed
  Stack:
    sandbox@resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.js -> resource://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/loader/sandbox.js:32:17
WorkerSandbox@resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.js -> resource://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/content/sandbox.js:145:19
constructor@resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.js -> resource://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/core/heritage.js:146:23
initialize@resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.js -> resource://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/content/worker-child.js:52:20
constructor@resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.js -> resource://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/core/heritage.js:146:23
@resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.js -> resource://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/content/tab-events.js:51:3
emitOnObject@resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.js -> resource://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/event/core.js:112:9
emit@resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.js -> resource://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/event/core.js:89:38
emitOnObject@resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.js -> resource://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/event/core.js:112:9
emit@resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.js -> resource://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/event/core.js:89:38
emitOnObject@resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.js -> resource://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/event/core.js:123:45
emit@resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.js -> resource://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/event/core.js:89:38
messageReceived@resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.js -> resource://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/remote/child.js:67:37
```

Works fine the first time it is attached, but when you navigate to another URL in the same tab, i get the above error. So probably when detaching and reattaching the script, something fails. Any help or idea is greatly appreciated and very welcomed!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Soo.. if you don't "jpm init" in the new folder, and copy-paste the contents of another, previously initialized folder, inside - you get the above error. Mistake on my part.